# Proving that a number is the greatest common factor.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

i have to prove that  Suppose p and q are prime numbers.
1 is a highest common factor of p and q if and only if $p \not= q$

And I'm clueless about where to start.

Which mathematical theorem/method (if any) that I could use to aid me with this question?

Comment: if $p$ and $q$ are primes, then they don't have any common factor other than $1$

Comment: What do you mean by $p$ $6=$ $q$. Could you perhaps write this part more clearly?

Comment: Do you mean... if and only if $p\ne q$?

Comment: Start from the definition of a prime number.

Answer (score 2):

For one direction, if $p=q$ they have a common factor of $p$.
For the other, if $p \neq q$, the only factors of $p$ are $\{1,p\}$ and the only factors of $q$ are $\{1,q\}$.  The only "one" in common is .....